# How to give a fragment the appearance of a dialog box?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have an Android game that's currently on the market and am in the process if implementing a turn-based multiplayer mode.  Unfortunately a large amount of unique activities are used within the game and Google Play Game Services require the game to work in a single activity using fragments.  For this reason I'm converting the project over to such a system (with android-support-v4).

I've written an abstraction layer which has helped the process and, as the game is already thoroughly tested in its current state, am hoping to avoid a major rewrite to change it from multiple activities to multiple fragments.  The game is working properly but I am having difficulties with the appearance of some of the fragments.

The main problem I'm facing is with the display of activities that inherited from **android:Theme.Dialog**.  I have a number of activities that display in floating dialog-style boxes but these are activities and not dialogs.  In the original code I had the following defined within styles.xml -

```
<style name="MyDialogStyle" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/my_border_graphic</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/MyDialogAnimations</item>
</style>
```

The activities that used this layout were defined in the manifest as -

```
<activity
    android:name="com.package.name.myactivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:theme="@style/MyDialogStyle" >
</activity>
```

Starting this activity results in a dialog style display exactly as would be expected from the style xml.  So far I have been unable to recreate this style for any of the fragments in my new code.  I have tried to use the style as follows -

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Context contextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.MyDialogStyle);
    LayoutInflater localInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(contextThemeWrapper);
    final View v = localInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, container, false);
    ...
```

But the resulting fragment appears in the top left of the screen.  Also, if it contains text that is very long, the fragment version uses the full screen width whereas the activity one wraps it in shortly lines.

Obviously I can play around with gravity settings to display things more centrally, but I don't see why I'm unable to use the style to control these factors as I did with an Activity.

Is it possible to display the fragment in a dialog style floating box?  If so, what changes do I need to make?  I am aware I can achieve the desired appearance by using a DialogFragment, calling setStyle in the onCreate and displaying it using show(...) but I want to keep it as a standard Fragment so it uses the same (or more similar) lifestyle to the previous activity method.

*[I've now realised I'm not going to get the same onPause/onResume lifecycle events in the dialog's hosting fragment - the dialog fragments are added rather than replacing the current fragment so they're not going to be called]*

Here's a small testbed I set up for playing around with the fragment code -

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new TestFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }

    public static class TestFragment extends DialogFragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final Context contextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.MyDialog);
            LayoutInflater localInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(contextThemeWrapper);
            final View v = localInflater.inflate(R.layout.test_dialog, container, false);
            return v;
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>
```

**test_dialog.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEST! TEST! TEST! TEST! TEST! TEST! TEST! TEST! TEST! TEST! TEST! TEST! TEST! TEST! TEST! TEST! TEST! TEST! TEST! TEST! TEST! TEST! TEST! TEST! TEST! TEST! TEST! TEST! TEST! TEST! TEST! TEST! TEST! TEST! TEST! TEST! TEST! TEST! TEST! TEST! TEST! TEST!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And this is the resultant output (looking nothing like a dialog) -

[image: Screenshot]

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: This is because your text is view too long, so the view takes all screen. You should change `layout_width` and `layout_height` in `test_dialog` with concrete values, or specify a `maxWidth` and height

Comment: You're missing the point that it's supposed to display like a dialog which would wrap the text within the dialog box and not expand the box to the full screen width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dialog fragment. It works exactly like a fragment and will look like a dialog when shown.

Comment: I've done some experimentation with this and have got it working.  There are a few subtleties involved - the container id must be set to zero and setStyle needs to be called from the constructor.  Unfortunately this doesn't work in the same way as an activity in that it doesn't cause onPause to be called in any other fragments (or onResume after the DialogFragment is dismissed).  This is a different issue though so I've marked this as the correct answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved the issue for myself, having a custom `View` that i wanted to float above other in a dialog style :

1. Set the background of the root view of my custom layout to 
   `android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"`
2. Then as you did, inflate the view using a custom dialog theme, for example `new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.MyDialogStyle)`

You then obtain an inflated view hierarchy whose root has background that's like a dialog window.

Note that this doesn't obscur the rest of the screen as dialogs do, just display a frame around your fragment.

Comment: Thanks.  It's not really the transparency that's the problem.  I've revised the question to be more specific.  The fragment doesn't resemble a dialog in any way - size, position, or anything else.

Comment: And did you try what i said ?

Comment: I did, yes. The fragment appears at the top of the screen and, when filled with lots of text, appears much wider than a standard dialog box. I've modified the question some more - using android:background as suggested gives the same display as shown in the screenshot but with a border around the text.